# Load, Open and Operate with RegEx, text files in Python

Tags: python, regex, file, path, directory

```
import re
import os

def scan_folder(parent):
    # iterate over all the files in directory 'parent'
    for file_name in os.listdir(parent):
        if file_name.endswith(".txt"):
            mensaje = file_name.read()
            mensaje = mensaje.replace("\n","")

            # Number of CVE from "DiarioOficial"
            regex = r"\s*CVE\s+([^|]*)"
            matches = re.search(regex, mensaje)
            if matches:
                print (matches.group(1).strip())
scan_folder("/Users/.../DiarioOficial")
```

I have the previous code to load and open all the .txt located in this route. I want to execute the function of Regex implemented for all the txt files that are in this route.

It does not work, it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anna/PycharmProjects/extractData/Principal.py", line 80, in <module>
    scan_folder("/Users/anna/PycharmProjects/extractData/DiarioOficial")
  File "/Users/anna/PycharmProjects/extractData/Principal.py", line 16, in scan_folder
    mensaje = file_name.read()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I want to go through all the files and operate the same in each one of them.

Comment: You never opened the file. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: `file_name` is a string, you need open the file first (with `open()` function) to read from file.

Answer (score 0):

you should replace:

```
mensaje = file_name.read()
```

with:

```
mensaje = open(file_name).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an open statement. file_name is a string object, it's just the name of the file. To open the file first you have to call open. Most convenient would be to use a with open like this as it saves you having to close the file manually:

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    mensaja = f.read()
```